# Spring server start-up event

Tags: spring, startup

i am facing a problem. I am using tomcat server for my spring maven project and i want to subscribe my application to facebook once when server starts up. I have tried ApplicationListener ContextRefreshedEvent. It gets invoked on application context initialization, but the issue is at that time my server has not completely started and hence my application is not publically accessible which is required in my case as facebook subscription requires verification using application public URL. So i want to do subscription when my server gets started completey and not on application context initialization. Any idea how can i do it? Do i have nay application level event listener that can tell me that server has started completely?

Regards jia

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate a bean method like so :

```
@PostConstruct
public void yrSubscribeLogic() {}
```

the app context can only be loaded after the server has fully started.

Comment: Nim, if this is the case then it means my server has successfully started. i am doing an http POST request to facebook API which in turn calls subscription verification service of my application and has a timeout set to 6s. I feel like, the issue is while my subscription request is generated it waits for response from facebook and facebook itself is trying to call subscription verification service of my same application which does not get entertained as my server is busy in subscription call and is waiting for response from facebook and so timeout occurs.

Comment: I should try by generating an async call to FB api.Any idea how can i do it using http post request in spring?